# Regular line pattern of flat pixels after using gdalwarp

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I observe a regular pattern of flat pixel bands on a DEM reprojected using [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html):

[image: Flat pixels bands]

The red line represents a profile for which the following graph is an extract between the two squared dots, so it crosses two flat pixel bands that are clearly visible:

[image: 2 of the flat bands on the profile]

I simply reprojected an original WGS84 DEM to the UTM of the region with:

```
$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:23032 input_dem.tif reprojected.tif;
```

The green line is the profile of the original WGS84 DEM, it's super smooth and it doesn't show the flat pixels pattern.

Is this a known issue? And what could I do to avoid this pattern?

#### Info:

The version of GDAL I use is from this Docker image `ubuntu-small-latest` available at https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal

```
# gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.0dev-33cf0e31a992be112b3091f012368d15605ed51d, released 2021/03/17
```

Comment: You're using the default nearest neighbour resampling method. Suggest you use a different resampling method. From the [doc](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) "-r <resampling_method> Resampling method to use. near: nearest neighbour resampling (default, fastest algorithm, worst interpolation quality)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through a lot of posts to figure out that, indeed, using the [nearest neighbor interpolation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation), in the case of a continuous raster such as a DEM, is not really a good idea. And that there is a mix between a "divinatory art" and an accumulated knowledge when it comes to applying filters.

In my case, the resulting re-projected raster is suffering some aliasing effects. I cannot explain why the repetitive pattern spacing is ~80 meters, which is not really 'near' (as in 'nearest neighbor'). And when I look closer (well, actually further), there is actually another pattern, oriented differently, with a much greater wavelength of roughly 650m.

Anyway, here are some great posts and answers out there that are worth reading imho:

[Deciding what interpolation method to use for resampling raster data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/deciding-what-interpolation-method-to-use-for-resampling-raster-data)

[What resampling technique should be used when projecting aerial photos?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17328/what-resampling-technique-should-be-used-when-projecting-aerial-photos)

[Pros and Cons of using Bilinear Interpolation and Cubic Convolution when dealing with DEMs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267433/pros-and-cons-of-using-bilinear-interpolation-and-cubic-convolution-when-dealing/267441#267441)

[Best Resampling Method for DEM reprojection in QGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102868/best-resampling-method-for-dem-reprojection-in-qgis)

[What resampling technique should be used to reproject an altitude raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121646/what-resampling-technique-should-be-used-to-reproject-an-altitude-raster)

[What is the source of horizontal and vertical striping in USGS DEMs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/what-is-the-source-of-horizontal-and-vertical-striping-in-usgs-dems/108957#108957)

[Why do "stripes" appear on raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191071/why-do-stripes-appear-on-raster/191077#191077)

[What is Lanczos resampling useful for in a spatial context?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/what-is-lanczos-resampling-useful-for-in-a-spatial-context)

Based on all these, I randomly decided to chose the bilinear interpolation when reprojecting my raster DEM. I was hesitating with the cubic or cubicspline offered by [the -r flag of gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r) as they also seem to be nice candidates. I also wanted to test the gaussian filter, but it doesn't seem to be available with gdalwarp.

The Lanczos method also looks great, but I prefer to avoid it when dealing with DEMs in order to not create altitudes that will extend out of the min-max range of the original DEM.

Here is a new line in blue, smoother and closer to the original DEM profile (green), representing the output result using the bilinear interpolation when re-projecting the DEM:

[image: Bilinear result]